# PHP create a bytearray of grayscale colors from 8x8 GD image

Tags: php, arrays, image-processing, gd

I have an image I've loaded from PHP using imagecreatefromjpeg.
I've successfully resized the image to 8x8 pixels, and I've successfully grayscaled the image ($img). Now I want the grayscale value of each pixel into an array ($ary).

I know about this (pseudocode):

```
for($x=0 ; $x<7; $x++){
    for($y=0 ; $y<7; $y++){
        $gry = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y)
        array_push($ary, $gry);
    }
}
```

but it seems like there should be a faster way to get the grayscale bytes into an array.

Is there a GD function I've overlooked, or perhaps a different approach to copying the 64 bytes into an array?

Can I do a reverse of imagecreatefromstring, add then explode that string into an array?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want just the colors, and don't care about where they are: `imagetruecolortopalette` => `imagecolorstotal` => `imagecolorsforindex`

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks - looks like imagecolorsforindex returns an rgb array.

Comment: Yep, but as its gray-scale, just converting that to using only the r (or g, or b, they should be the same) should be enough for the grey scale. If that doesn't suffice, your current solution is about the best you can do AFAIK.

Comment: I realized that I have to loop through them anyway to convert them to 256-bit values from RGB. I'm not sure which is faster: imagecreatefromstring then looping through the results, or just looping through with imagecolorat. The first one seems more viable as the result set is filled by C rather than by PHP. I'll try them both and report my findings. My current RGB-to-gray formula is using the ratio I've seen all over: r*.299, g*.587 and b*.114. If I use the same formula for all of my processes, I believe the results will be consistent. I'm extracting a perceptual hash.